# после проверки на существование треугольника были предложены на выбор способы вычисления площади, у меня вычисляются обе формулы, хотя одну надо

Tags: python

```
a=int(input("Введите длину стороны a="))
b=int(input("Введите длину стороны b="))
c=int(input("Введите длину сторны c="))
if a<b+c and b<a+c and c<b+a:
    print("Такой треугольниик существует")
    print("Способы вычисления:")
    print("По стороне и высоте, опущенную на данную сторону 1")
    print("По формуле Герона 2")
    input("Выберите способ вычисления:")
    if 1:
        h=int(input("Введите длину высоты, опущенную на сторону a, h="))
        S=a*h
        print("S=",S)
    if 2:
        S=(a+b+c)/2
        print("S=",S)
else:
    print("Такого треугольника не существует")
```

Comment: Вторая формула - это не площадь, а полупериметр.  Площадь посложнее, формулу Герона-то посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

input() - функция которая возвращает значение введенное пользователем. Его надо записывать в переменную, а после сравнивать ее с результатом.

```
a=int(input("Введите длину стороны a="))
b=int(input("Введите длину стороны b="))
c=int(input("Введите длину сторны c="))
if a<b+c and b<a+c and c<b+a:
    print("Такой треугольниик существует")
    print("Способы вычисления:")
    print("По стороне и высоте, опущенную на данную сторону 1")
    print("По формуле Герона 2")
    user_input = input("Выберите способ вычисления:")
    if user_input == "1":
        h=int(input("Введите длину высоты, опущенную на сторону a, h="))
        S=a*h
        print("S=",S)
    if user_input == "2":
        S=(a+b+c)/2
        print("S=",S)
else:
    print("Такого треугольника не существует")
```

Цифры в кавычках т.к. пользователь в любом случае вводит текст, и тип переменной user_input будет string(текст)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!!!! Я весь интернет перерыл и не смог ничего найти, теперь запомню алгоритм